# C# LocalReport: how to add custom code from a different directory

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, localreport

I'm using the `Microsoft Reporting Services` in a `.NET Framework 4.8` application, using the `LocalReport` class to rendere a .rdlc report.

In my report, I'm using some custom code from some additional assemblies, that I added to the report via de Report Properties -> References menu.

In my code, when I render the report, I add the assemblies do the LocalReport domain to make them available in the report, with some code like this:

```
var assemblyName = myCustomAssembly.GetName();
var strongAssemblyName = new StrongName(new StrongNamePublicKeyBlob(assemblyName.GetPublicKeyToken()), assemblyName.Name, assemblyName.Version)
localReport.AddFullTrustModuleInSandboxAppDomain(strongAssemblyName);
```

Now, this works perfectly... **but only if the .DLL that contains the assembly I'm trying to add is in the same folder as my executable**. If it is somewhere else (for example, in my case, in a subfolder) the report generation fails, with an exception telling me assembly could not be loaded because the dll file could not be found.

Is there a way to solve this? Can I tell the LocalReport to load the assemblies from a specific folder, or add a search path in some way? Or is the only solution to have the assemblies in the root folder of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a lot of answers to other posts here on SO suggested to make it work by adding the subfolder(s) I needed to the domain's `SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath` property. This, however, didn't seem to have any effect at all. In fact, if I read the `SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath` property immediately after setting it, I got `null` in return.

So, I've dug deeper and decompiled part of the .NET Framework source code to get to the bottom of it.

First of all: it should be noted that the report processing happens in a sandboxed `AppDomain` that is created specifically for generating the report, it doesn't run directly on the app's main domain. However, by decompiling the `ReportViewer` assemblies, I've found that the sandboxed domain is constructed with the setup information taken from the base `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation`, so any paths set there should also be available to the report generation.

From what I can see, the root problem is this: the `SetupInformation` property of the `AppDomain` class seems to return a **copy** of the `SetupInformation`. So, setting anything in there is absolutely useless, because you're operating on a copy that is then discarded.

What ended up working, was setting [this property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in the `App.config` file, like this:

```
<probing privatePath="my\sub\path"/>
```

and that solved the issue!

I'm still curious if there is a way to actually set the probing path dynamically in code rather than having it hardcoded in the .config file, any comment in that direction is welcome.